# Accessing other models in a Sequelize model hook function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a model hook that automatically creates an associated record when the main model has been created. How can I access my other models within the hook function when my model file is structured as follows?

```
/**
 * Main Model
 */
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var MainModel = sequelize.define('MainModel', {

    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }

  }, {

    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {

        MainModel.hasOne(models.OtherModel, {
          onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true
        });

      }
    },

    hooks: {

      afterCreate: function(mainModel, next) {
        // ------------------------------------
        // How can I get to OtherModel here?
        // ------------------------------------
      }

    }

  });


  return MainModel;
};
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can access the other model through `sequelize.models.OtherModel`.

Comment: `sequelize` is not available.

Comment: `sequelize` should be available on `instance.sequelize` (`mainModel.sequelize` in the original question).

Comment: omg! thank you so much. you just saved me from an hour of confusion

Comment: the best practice is for check hasMany right ? so whenever the root have 3 child (hasMany) should change status column on root , may i right ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `this.associations.OtherModel.target`.

```
/**
 * Main Model
 */
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var MainModel = sequelize.define('MainModel', {

    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }

  }, {

    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {

        MainModel.hasOne(models.OtherModel, {
          onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true
        });

      }
    },

    hooks: {

      afterCreate: function(mainModel, next) {
        /**
         * Check It!
         */
        this.associations.OtherModel.target.create({ MainModelId: mainModel.id })
        .then(function(otherModel) { return next(null, otherModel); })
        .catch(function(err) { return next(null); });
      }

    }

  });


  return MainModel;
};
```