# Lifecycle hooks with sequelize on a different model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've been looking through this but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Basically I have two models.

"X" and "Y"

On lifecycle events of Y(which defines a belongsTo to X) I'm supposed to be updating(incrementing) the values of X. I'll illustrate with code in a while but this is the gist of it.

So whenever I create an entry of Y a value inside X must increment by 1.

Using a require to the sequelize generated Index.js function didn't seem to do anything and I don't want to add even more complexity to my main routes.js file.

This is the "X" model code(named User):

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                len: [4, 32]
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            required: true,
            protect: true,
            validate: {
                len: [4, 32]
            }

        },
        likedByCount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        user_likes:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue:0
        }
    });
    user.associate = function (models) {
        models.user.hasMany(models.like, {
            onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
    };
    user.beforeCreate((user) => {
        return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hashedPw => {
            console.log(user.password + " hash " + hashedPw);
            user.password = hashedPw;
        });
    });
    user.beforeUpdate((user) => {
        return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hashedPw => {
            console.log(user.password + " hash " + hashedPw);
            user.password = hashedPw;
        });

    });

    return user;


};
```

And this is the "Y" model definition:

```
    const moduleFile = require("./index.js");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    sequelize
        .sync()
        .then(function (err) {
            console.log('Sync successful');
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while creating the table:', err);
        });
    const like = sequelize.define('like', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            required: true,
        },
        target_username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        source_username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        target: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }

    });
    //HasOne and BelongsTo insert the association key in different models from each other. 
    //HasOne inserts the association key in target model whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.
    like.associate = function (models) {
        models.like.belongsTo(models.user, {
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    };
    ""
    //Update the field likedByCount of target user by +1, update the field likes of source user by 1
    like.afterCreate((like) => {

        const target_id = like.target_id;
        const source_id = like.source_id;
        moduleFile.user.findById(target_id).then(user => {
             user.increment('likedByCount', {
                by: 1
            })
        }).catch((err)=>console.log("Decrement error" + err.message));
    });


    return like;

};
```

My code obviously produces an error because "moduleFiles" isn't found correctly. But I do it the same way in router.js:

```
var models = require("../models/index.js");

Folder structure checks out:

/ :index.js(this just launches the server)
/models/: index.js,user.js,like.js
/routes/: routes.js(this is where the above code(var models=) is from
```

Comment: old but this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313763/accessing-other-models-in-a-sequelize-model-hook-function